# Cómo crear un vector con una longitud específica en R

Tags: r

Quiero construir un vector de longitud 7 llamado `x` con los siguientes valores: `2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17.`

Sé que el vector se crearía así, y que la longitud es `7`, pero hay alguna forma de asegurarse de que tenga longitud `7`?

```
x <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17)
```

Otro vector de longitud `3` llamado `y` con los siguientes valores: `2, 3, 5`

Asimismo formar un vector de longitud `5` llamado `z` compuesto por los tres primeros valores del vector `y`, los otros dos valores iguales al vector `x`.

Comment: Bienvenido @Maria a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe el método `length` en **R** que te permite saber que longitud tiene un vector

```
x <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17) 
length(x) # Se imprime 7
```

Asimismo es importante indicar que en **R** los indices empiezan por `uno`

```
x[1] # Se imprime 2
x[4] # Se imprime 7
```

Por otro lado si quieres obtener un rango en un vector se emplea `:` para indicar el inicio y fin del rango

```
x[1:3] # Se imprime 2 3 5

y<-x[1:3]
y      # Se imprime 2 3 5
```

También es posible combinar vectores usando `c()`

```
c(c(1,2,3),4:6) # Se imprime 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

En el caso de `z` se tendría lo siguiente por ejemplo

```
z <- c(y,x[4:5]) # Se imprime 2  3  5  7 11
```